# Compare if datetime.timedelta is between two values

Tags: python

I have a datetime.timedelta time object in python (e.g. 00:02:00) I want to check if this time is less than 5 minutess and greater then 1 minute.

I'm not sure how to construct a timedelta object and I'm also not sure if this is the right format to compare times. Would anyone know the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean you don't know how to construct a timedelta object? Have you looked at the docs? Have you even tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So if you start with a string that's rigorously and precisely in the format `'HH:MM:SS'`, `timedelta` doesn't directly offer a string-parsing function, but it's not hard to make one:

```
import datetime

def parsedelta(hhmmss):
    h, m, s = hhmmss.split(':')
    return datetime.timedelta(hours=int(h), minutes=int(m), seconds=int(s))
```

If you need to parse many different variants you'll be better off looking for third-party packages like `dateutil`.

Once you do have  `timedelta` instance, the check you request is easy, e.g:

```
onemin = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
fivemin = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)

if onemin < parsedelta('00:02:00') < fivemin:
    print('yep')
```

will, as expected, display `yep`.